# Prove that $f(1999)=1999$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, contest-math

A function $f$ maps from the positive integers to the positive integers, with the following properties:
$$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and
$$f(p+q)=f(p)+f(q)$$ for all prime numbers $p$ and $q$. Prove that $f(2)=2, f(3)=3$, and $f(1999)=1999$.

It is simple enough to prove that $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=3$, but I'm struggling with $f(1999)=1999$. 
I tried proving the general solution of $f(n)=n$ for all $n$ with a proof by contradiction: suppose $x$ is the smallest $x$ such that $f(x)<x$. I'm struggling find a way to show that no such $x$ exists if $x=p^m$ for $p$ a prime.

Can anyone help me finish off the $p^m$ case, or else show me another way of finding the answer? Computers and calculators are not allowed.

Comment: is $1$ a prime?     what is $f(1)$?

Comment: Can you show us your work for $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=3$? I could find $f(2)=2$ but don't exactly see how $f(3)=3$, even though you're stating it to be "simple enough"

Comment: 1 is not prime...

Comment: @Mirko, $1$ is not prime in the usual sense, but we can easily find $f(1)$ by setting $a=b=1$ in the first property so $f(1^2)=f(1)^2$ implying $f(1)=1$ (since $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, so $f(1)\neq 0$)

Comment: @Martigan I know but I am asking the OP, what is $f(1)$. I would say $f(1)=f(1\cdot1)=f(1)f(1)$, hence $f(1)=1$. If $1$ were a prime, then $f(3)=f(2)+f(1)=2+1=3$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel, I also don't see how f(3) = 3, without assuming 1,2 are prime, (1,2) coprime and applying the 2th property..

Comment: @Mirko I assume $1$ not to be a prime for otherwise the question is much easier.

Comment: @lmago, I saw that too, and think that's where to confusion of $1$ being prime or not comes from. I'll be trying to construct a consistent function satisfying the properties with $f(3)\neq 3$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel $f(18)=f(9)f(2)=f(13)+f(5)$, and $f(9)=f(3)+6$, and $f(13)=f(11)+2$, and we solve for $f(11)$ in terms of $f(3)$ by solving $f(14)=f(2)f(7)=f(11)+f(3)$. Do you see it now? I also found $f(7)=f(3)+4$,

Comment: @vrugtehagel,$f(4)=f(2)+f(2)=4,f(12)=f(3)f(4)=4f(3)=f(5)+f(7)=3f(2)+2f(3)$, so $f(3)=3$

Comment: Is it true that $f(n)=n$ for all $n$?

Comment: I think considering $f(27)$ should be interesting, since it can't be directly involved in either relation.  Can anyone show that $f(27)=27$?

Comment: @Nate you have to work down to $f(27)$; $f(27)=f(29)-2=f(31)-4=f(33)-6=33-6=27$. $f(33)=f(3)f(11)$ which we already figured out.

Comment: $27$ is not prime, so you don't know that $f(27) +f(2) = f(29)$

Comment: @Nate You're right. But $f(54)=2f(27)=f(23)+f(31)$, which I figured out just there. So it can be found.

Comment: 1 is not prime but 1 and n are coprime so $f(n) = f(1n) = f(1)f(n)$ for all n. So if $f(n) \ne 0$ $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: $f(54) = 2f(27) = f(47) + f(7)=f(43) + f(11)= f(41) + f(13)=f(37)+f(17)=f(31)+f(23)$.  It's not hard to show f(7,11,13) = 7,11,13.  I think we can prove the other primes.  f(17)+ f(3) = f(4*5) = 20 so f(17) = 17.  $f(37+3)=f(40) = f(8)f(5) = 40$ so $f(37)= 37$ so $f(54)= f(37)+f(17) = 54$ and $f(54) = f(2)f(27) = 2f(27)$ so $f(27) = 27$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2002= 1999+3, both 1999 and 3 are primes, so $f(2002)=f(1999)+f(3)$.

The prime factorization of 2002 is: 2002=2*7*11*13.

Therefore

$f(2002) = f(2)f(7)f(11)f(13)$

Now $f(7) = f(5+2) = f(5)+f(2) = f(2)+f(3)+f(2) = 7$,

$f(14) = f(11)+f(3) $ but also $f(14) = f(2) f(7)=14$, therefore $f(11)=11$ (thank you @lulu for the correction).

Finally,

$f(13)=f(11)+f(2) = 13$, and we have

$$f(2002)=2002$$

It follows that $f(1999) = f(2002)-f(3)=1999$.

Comment: How do you determine $f(11) = f(5) + f(6)$?

Comment: Very much annoyed I didn't see this sooner. Thank you.

Comment: If you know $f(2)=2,f(3)=3$ then:  $f(5)=5\implies f(7)=7\implies f(14)=14$ but then $14=f(14)=f(11+3)=f(11)+3\implies f(11)=11$.

Comment: oops... (I swapped multiplication with addition) thanks for the correction !

Comment: Is it possible that $f(n)\ne n$ for some $n$?

Comment: I have a hunch that proving f(n) = n is equivalent to some unsolved prime conjecture.  Let n be the first $f(n) \ne n$ then $n$ is prime, is not the sum of primes, and n plus all smaller primes aren't composite.  It's hard to imagine such a number, but I don't see a proof that such a number can't exist either.  Oh, I guess n could be a power of a prime.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a sketch of a "proof" that $f(n) = n $ for all $n$.

Let's prove it by strong induction on $n$, where the small cases are in various comments.

**Case 1:** $n$ is composite, not a prime power. Write $n = ab$ with $a, b$ coprime.  Applying the first equation gives: $f(n) = f(a)f(b)$, which is $ab=n$ by induction.

**Case 2:** $n$ is prime (and large enough since we have base cases) then $n+3$ is composite and we can run the same argument as case 1 to that (without needing to know that $f(n)=n$) and see that $f(n+3) = n+3$. Now the second equation gives $f(n)=n$ as desired.

**Edit: Case 2b:** Marco Disce pointed out in the comments that I missed the case where $n$ is prime and $n+3$ is a power of $2$, in this case we can run the same argument as case $2$ but with $n+5$ instead of $n+3$ (they can't both be powers of 2).

Now for the remaining cases I will need a small lemma, the proof of which I will leave as an exercise to the reader:

**Lemma:** The Goldbach conjecture holds.

**Case 3:** $n = 2^k$, write $n = p+q$ for odd primes $p,q$ and use the second equation.

**Case 4:** $n = p^k$ for some odd $p$ and $k>1$.  Write $2n = q+q'$ with $q,q'$ prime and $q' < n$. We still need to check that $f(q) = q$, but we can now apply the same argument as case 2 to see this, with the caveat that if $q' = 3$ we should instead show that $f(q+5)=q+5$ so as to avoid needing the $n$ case.

Comment: Did I miss something? The Goldbach conjecture is a simple lemma?  Although it certainly has no counter-examples below some very large number a lot bigger than 1999.

Comment: @user254665 adjust your humor meter.  Nate was making a joke.  f(n) = n if the Goldbach Conjecture holds.  If it doesn't ... well, then it doesn't have to.  (I think)

Comment: @fleablood. I knew he couldn't possibly be serious.I thought it would be easy to prove f(n)=n for all n by induction,  and I ran into trouble, and saw the Goldbach Conjecture  would be useful, maybe necessary, and I stopped. Do u think it would  be a good one to post ? ( i mean if f(n) must be n for all n)

Comment: Why if $n$ is prime then $n+3$ falls under case1? $2^k-3$ is never prime?

Comment: @MarcoDisce good catch! I made an edit to address that case.