# Functional equation on integers: $f(m\cdot n)=f(m)f(n)$ and $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Find all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m \cdot n) = f(m) f(n)$ for $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ and $f(m + n) = f(m) + f(n)$ for $\forall m, n \in \mathbb{P}$.

I think only solution should be $f(n) = n, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$...
But I only managed to show $f(3) = 3$ and for other small primes...

Comment: A very similar question was asked yesterday:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693214/prove-that-f1999-1999  I believe someone there proved the desired result (assuming Goldbach's conjecture).

Comment: what is $f(1)?$

Comment: $f(1)=1$, just assume $n=1$ and from first condition get that...

Comment: I see, $\mathbb P$ means primes. Then this is the same as yesterday's question